# Declaring a function noexcept conditionally on the testing flag?

Tags: c++, testing, assert, throw, noexcept

If one is using exceptions to replace assertions for debugging/testing purposes.

**Does it make sense to declare a function `noexcept` conditionally on the testing flag or this would mess too much with the function interface?**

```
#ifdef MYTESTING
#define MYASSERT(x) if(not x) throw std::logic_error("error not "#x)
#else
#define MYASSERT(x) assert(x);
#endif

double f(double x) 
#if not defined(MYTESTING)
noexcept
#endif
{
   MYASSERT(x >= 0);
   return legacy_c_function(x);
}
```

(I know that `legacy_c_function` is a C function and it is not going to throw an exception).

I [know](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/04/25/the-lakos-rule/) that many (standard) function are not declared `noexcept` just in case one wants to test the function internally.

In principle this could have the best of both worlds?

Although unlikely (?), I can see that this method of testing might have diminished value because it can have observable effects in other parts of the code that depend on the `noexcept`ness of this function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm curious what you expect to gain from replacing `assert` with `throw`.

Comment: There is no thing like *std::logical_error*. Perhaps you meant `std::logic_error`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, the ability to check failures from testing code (e.g. unit testing). hard assert could abort the program entirely.

Comment: @alfC That seems like a reasonable goal. However you may be underevaluating the impact of breaking the `noexcept` promise. You might be able to get away with it if the function is a high level API function, but this solution probably should not be used for anything else. Other code that relies on your `noexcept`ness may count on it to avoid leaks, information loss or even UB. Edit : in many cases, `noexcept` functions are called from other `noexcept` functions. Unless you remove `noexcept` from all of them, you will end up terminating anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yeah, I suspected something on those lines. I guess I can do it when the `noexcept` doesn't matter. And if the `noexcept` doesn't matter it shouldn't be there in the first place. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: Note that (the `noexcept(false)` half of) the Lakos rule was overturned recently; current standard library policy is to make things `noexcept` if they aren’t *specified* to throw (and don’t call user code).

Comment: @DavisHerring mmm, why was it overturned? I though it had a solid justification. Maybe it doesn’t matter if user code cannot be called (?) because it cannot be tested ?

Comment: @alfC: There is [a paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1656r2.html), to which I would add that I have no problem with a `noexcept` function throwing an exception as an instance of undefined behavior.